# jQuery .hide() hiding too early

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery to make a progressbar move,and when done show some text.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/8fLbfpqc/)

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <div class="demo-wrapper html5-progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-bar-wrapper">
            <progress id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress>  <span class="progress-value">0%</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var progressbar = $('#progressbar'),
        max = progressbar.attr('max'),
        time = (1000 / max) * 5,
        value = progressbar.val();

    var loading = function () {
        value += 1;
        addValue = progressbar.val(value);

        $('.progress-value').html(value + '%');

        if (value == max) {
            clearInterval(animate);

            $("#dialog").css('background', 'none').html('<br>Open your <a href="http://gmail.com" target="_blank">Gmail</a> to confirm your account.<br><br>Click the <i>View Account Details</i> button to view your details.').dialog("option", "title", "Your Account Has Been Created!");
        }
    };

    var animate = setInterval(function () {
        loading();
    }, time);

});


$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        width: 1000,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        title: "Creating Your Account...",
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            text: "View Account Details",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog().html('<some_html>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This code hides everything, nothing shows up at all. I want the dialog to have a progressbar inside it, and when it's done, for some text to replace the content. What is wrong with this?

Comment: When I disabled jQuery UI, everything loaded perfectly.  I would try it on localhost and make sure you link correctly to jQuery UI, because it seems at the moment it's just making the whole thing display:none.

Comment: Have you looked into why it's throwing the error *"Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '0' is not a valid attribute name."*?

Comment: No, I am no good at debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem originates at the `buttons` property of the `dialog` method, you're using it incorrectly.

[The jQuery UI documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons) mentions that you can pass either an array or an object to `buttons`.

- **If you decide to pass it an object**, each key is the text that appears on
  the button, and the method is what executes when you click it.
- **If you pass it an array *of objects***, each object in the array defines properties for
  each button.

Since you're passing it an object with the sort of format you have to use when you pass it an array, jQuery UI is getting confused, and throwing this error:

```
"Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '0' is not a valid attribute name."
```

So the solution would be to give it an object with the correct format.

**This will create two buttons, one that says "Ok" and closes the dialog, and the "View account details" button:**

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fLbfpqc/3/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var progressbar = $('#progressbar'),
        max = progressbar.attr('max'),
        time = (1000 / max) * 5,
        value = progressbar.val();

    var loading = function () {
        value += 1;
        addValue = progressbar.val(value);

        $('.progress-value').html(value + '%');

        if (value == max) {
            clearInterval(animate);

            $("#dialog").css('background', 'none').html('<br>Open your <a href="http://gmail.com" target="_blank">Gmail</a> to confirm your account.<br><br>Click the <i>View Account Details</i> button to view your details.').dialog("option", "title", "Your Account Has Been Created!");
        }
    };

    var animate = setInterval(function () {
        loading();
    }, time);

});


$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        width: 1000,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        title: "Creating Your Account...",
        buttons: {
            "View account details": function () {
                $(this).dialog().html('<table><tr><td>Your username is:</td><td><input type="text" readonly value="hell;o"></td></tr><tr><td>Your password is:</td><td><input type="text" readonly value=""></td></tr><tr><td>Your email is:</td><td><input type="text" style="overflow:scroll;" value=""></td></tr></table><br><br>Open your <a href="http://gmail.com" target="_blank">Gmail</a> to confirm your account.');
            },
            "Ok": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="dialog">
    <div class="demo-wrapper html5-progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-bar-wrapper">
            <progress id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress> <span class="progress-value">75%</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<center></center>
```